# Messaging system for c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, email

I am trying to find a solution that can handle messaging via email.
When a user creates a message in my application, an email is sent using subject #4857474.
Then, the email recipient can reply, without changing the subject, and my application would know what message it used, based on the #id in the subject.

Now, I do not want to implement such service because its rather complex. What I am looking for is a service that provides this, and just calls my web services for a request when a new message has arrived.

Is there such thing? Thanks!

Comment: 'Messaging system' is a bit of a confusing title. Messaging brings to mind JMS or ActiveMQ, used to send messages around/between enterprise applications. Might be a few people looking at this question expecting it to be about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the smtp standard there are two header fields that can be used for this: [`message-id`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Header_fields) and [`in-reply-to`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Header_fields).

Assign a unique message id when you send the mail, then inspect the in-reply-to field in messages you receive. Since the field is hidden from user input, there is no risk that the user messes with it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a default component you could use. Also it wouldn't be a very complex flow i think.

Just read out the subject and trigger your app?

Is email a must or can you also use a webbased reply form? Then you could use just a database.

Edit:

Read email from C# http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx

Create a thread that runs for ever and reads out the mailbox. If a email matches your criteria (subject) then trigger your webservice.

Comment: Yes, but the content is appended with instructions like 'Do not edit the subject bla bla bla' and I dont want to catch other text rather than the new reply. (exlude all the Outlook reply headers etc)

Comment: Just parse the message header for the subject (in code) and then parse the body.

Comment: I'd agree that its not too complex, unless there is the chance that the subject will has been edited, in which case just using the subject could cause problems. You might want to have something inside the message body as a backup check.